# Exporting boolean values to CSV

Tags: ms-access, export-to-csv, dbeaver

When i export a MS access Table to CSV file. The Boolean values with be either True or False. Is there any settings I can change so that 1 is true and 0 is False?

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting. Calculate a field in query to display whatever you want in lieu of -1. Export the query.

`SELECT field1, field2, Abs([field3]) AS F3 FROM tablename;`

Use IIf() if you want something other than a number:

`IIf(field3, "True", "False")`

Comment: Or simply: `Abs([field3]) As F3`.